# Uneven starting column alignments with large columns

Tags: columns

The following produces four tables, which I boxed to make them clearer.

The bottom two boxes are of even starting heights, but the top two are not.

I would like for the top pair of boxes to start at the exact same height like the bottom pair does. Is there some sort of padding parameter that I am not taking advantage of?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{document}

Uneven column heights:
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}\nonumber
        \begin{matrix}
        \text{Title number 1} & \text{Title number 2} & \text{Title Number 3}\\
        1a & 2a & 3a\\
        1b & 2b & 3b\\
        1c & 2c & 3c
        \end{matrix}
        \end{empheq}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}\nonumber
        \begin{matrix}
        \text{Title no. 4} & \text{Title no. 5} & \text{Title no. 6}\\
        4a & 5a & 6a\\
        4b & 5b & 6b\\
        4c & 5c & 6c
        \end{matrix}
        \end{empheq}
    \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}

\vspace{1cm}
Even column heights:
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}\nonumber
        \begin{matrix}
        \text{Title no. 1} & \text{Title no. 2} & \text{Title no. 3}\\
        1a & 2a & 3a\\
        1b & 2b & 3b\\
        1c & 2c & 3c
        \end{matrix}
        \end{empheq}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}\nonumber
        \begin{matrix}
        \text{Title no. 4} & \text{Title no. 5} & \text{Title no. 6}\\
        4a & 5a & 6a\\
        4b & 5b & 6b\\
        4c & 5c & 6c
        \end{matrix}
        \end{empheq}
    \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the `multicols`? Can't you just place 2 `minipages` sode by side?

Comment: The reason for the uneven placement seem to be the headers in the top left box that make the whole box wider than the assigned space. (Try to shorten the `\text`s and compare the results.) Also notice the overfulll box warnings.

Comment: I am aware of the large headers. In the application I am running, I NEED those large headers.

I need to know how I can fit those titles into the alloted space. I will change whatever padding parameter I can...if I can find that parameter.

Comment: You can use a simple `box=\fbox`  for the environment with the longest headers.